# atexit() function bionic vs glibc

Tags: c++, g++, glibc, bionic

I found interesting moment: the `atexit()` function works differently for `bionic` and `glibc`. Here is an example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
extern "C" {
    void one(){
    printf("one\n");
    }
    void two() {
    printf("two\n");
    atexit(one);
    }
}
int main() {
    atexit(two);
}
```

**Results for `bionic`:**

```
two
```

**Results for `glibc`:**

```
two
one
```

Why do the results differ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is unspecified whether a call to the `atexit` function that does not happen before the `exit` function is called will succeed.

ISO C standard, §7.22.4.2. So both behaviors are compliant; you can't reliably register a function using `atexit` while `exit` is already running its `atexit` handlers.

Comment: Where i can found standart? do you mean 7.20.4.2>

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is unspecified. You can define multiple functions to be called using `atexit()` multiple times, but you must not use it once you're already exiting the program (i.e. once you've left `main()`).